# Will r-base on ubuntu give me the same interface as RStudio with R on Windows?

Tags: software-installation, r

It's my first year in uni and our stats course requires the use of R. The lab computers we use is on a Windows computer running RStudio and I read that you need to install RStudio and R for that to work.

My laptop however, is running Ubuntu, and when I looked for how to install R on Ubuntu, it says just use `sudo apt install r-base`. Will this give me the same interface as the one used on Windows computers running RStudio and R?

Comment: If you want R Studio, why not install it? https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Comment: I have no idea how to install, but the web page offers downloadable debians for Ubuntu https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://www.thertrader.com/2014/09/22/installing-rrstudio-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Download the appropriate .deb file from https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ and then install it using `sudo dpkg -i`.

Comment: better to use `gdebi` for installation as it automatically resolves the dependencies: `sudo apt-get install gdebi-core && sudo gdebi <rstudio.deb>`

Comment: the answer to your question, btw, is no. r-base is not the same as rstudio

Answer (score 2):

1. Install r-base first using the command you mentioned; that gives you a command-line interface to R.
2. Then install RStudio from [this page](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) (look under "installers" and pick the `.deb` file that corresponds to your computer's architecture (32- or 64-bit)).
3. After you've downloaded the `.deb` file, change directory to wherever that file was downloaded to (using `cd` command, for example `cd ~/Downloads`) and install it via `sudo dpkg -i rstudio-0.99.902-amd64.deb` (or whatever the downloaded `.deb` file is called).

After successful install, you can delete the `.deb` file.

Comment: better to use `gdebi` for installation as it automatically resolves the dependencies: `sudo apt-get install gdebi-core && sudo gdebi <rstudio.deb>`